# AJAX 404 Not Found error

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, jboss

I am facing some problem while working on **JBOSS 4.0.2** .

What I am trying to do is to make a simple AJAX call from a jsp file to a servlet class file which is stored in the **`WEB-INF/classes/servlet here`**.

The hierarchy is like this:

```
server/ABC/deploy/xyz.war/customform/form/a.jsp
server/ABC/deploy/xyz.war/WEB-INF/classes/abc.class
```

added this manually in **web.xml**

`<servlet><servlet-name>abc</servlet-name><servlet-class>abc</servlet-class></servlet>`

**....**

`<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>abc</servlet-name><url-pattern>/abc</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>`

URL in AJAX is same as given in the **`<url-pattern>`**

**I get AJAX status "404" when send requset to the servlet.**

Also, when I used alert box to show the status, it replied **"Unspecified error"** and after that **status=404** for  **readyState=2** , **readyState=3** , **readyState=4**

I can't figure it out that why it is not able to call the servlet.

Are there other steps required to be done for calling that servlet that I am missing,

**or**

If I went somewhere wrong, please point out the mistake.

It would be a great help if someone posts the steps to be done for such a calling to the servlet.

Comment: If you open your app in google chrome, open the console and enable xhr request logging, which url does it try to access?
Are you able to access it if you right click and open in new tab?

Comment: How about `/xyz/abc`? The name of the `war` or the context of the application might need to be appended

Comment: @MichaelDibbets not able to open it in chrome, window where form is displayed opens and vanishes...
What about firefox and IE

Comment: In IE press F12 and check out the different tabs etc... Try to find the url your ajax script actually calls to. That is where the error comes from.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets The ajax script is calling the same url as given inside it,and the **"Unspecified error"** is shown where I alert the status. After that the status is alerted as "404" and the readyState changes to 1,2,3,4...The problem actually is that my script is not able to find the servlet class file but I don't know why...

Comment: If you type in the url that ajax calls manually, what happens then?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets If I put the servlet class file in the **xyz.war** folder **(out of the WEB-INF,not removing from the WEB-INF)** and try to access it by `localhost:portno/xyz/abc` url following error occurs:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servlet instance
...

root cause 

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
...
Shall I post the complete error or is this ok?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Also on accessing it through ajax, it shows **`status=500`**

Answer (score 1):

well then it seems your either of the following:
programming error, too bad it doesnt show line number OR your server software needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for all your time spent on my problem.Actually I got it working.It was a matter of some jars to be placed in right folders.Also I was using annotations in the servlet,which caused the **Bad version number in .class file** error.
Thanks again for all your help
:)